# How to set visibility of TextView?

Tags: android, android-view

I want to check! For example - if (tv.Visible == true) then showMessage ("Yee it's Visible") else ("Its not visible"); I hope you're understand!

Comment: To hide the view you can use the setVisibility() method of the TextView.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You provide very little information, but I think this is what you are after...

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
tv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

You will need to adjust the id to your own.

EDIT: You can check to see if the TextView is already invisible by:

```
if (tv.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
    // do something.
}
```