# How to view only two TextView in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a questionnaire, in which I want the user to see only the previous and current question. How to achieve this in Android.
This is my XML View. 
The user can see maximum two questions -- previous and current. 
I have used a `RelativeLayout` which contains `ScrollView`, and in that I'm using multiple `TextView` for questions and `Button` for true/false

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.ScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:fillViewport="false"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.scanqr_android.ScrollingActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_scrolling">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="#3f51b5"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="MY PAGE TITLE"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#fff" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Caterpillars turn into butterflies."
                tools:text="Caterpillars turn into butterflies." />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="true" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="false" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Bubble gum contains rubber."
                tools:text="Bubble gum contains rubber." />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="true" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button8"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="false" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="The deadliest earthquake of 2017 took place in Iran and Iraq." />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/Button9"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="true" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button10"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="false" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Electrons are larger than molecules." />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button11"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="true" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button12"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="false" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView12"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Thunderstorms have particular sound frequencies that can hurt a dog’s ears." />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button13"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="true" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button14"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="false" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView13"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=" There are 30 days in May." />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button15"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="true" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button16"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="false" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you can programmatically show/hide textviews using setVisiblity(). And hide / show the next / previous items by checking conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly register your `layout` id by using `findViewById()` in `java file`.
Then you can hide the layout of `textviews` using like this -

`linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);`  by checking conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You just hide the textview like this

```
textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

or

```
textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Take a look at this [How to set visibility of TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34822485/how-to-set-visibility-of-textview)